# Python: Using variable in for loop for substitution

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to condense repetition in a Python program that utilizes pygame. I currently have some number of lines that are like this:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_q]: q.PerformNote()
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]: w.PerformNote()
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_e]: e.PerformNote()
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_r]: r.PerformNote()
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_t]: t.PerformNote()
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
keyList = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't']
for currentKey in keyList:
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_currentKey]:
        currentKey.PerformNote()
```

The resulting error is

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'K_currentKey'

I think I might have spent too much time in BASH recently as this construct makes perfect sense to my brain. I've searched around with no idea of the proper way to implement this.

Comment: Take a look at [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: your keyList should contain pygame.K_*, not directly letters names

Comment: (also, in bash there would be something to indicate the use of the variable. probably ${} or something.)

Comment: maybe you need a dictionary map of a letter to the K_*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map pygame keys to their corresponding variables:

```
keyMap = {
    pygame.K_q: q,
    pygame.K_w: w,
    pygame.K_e: e,
    pygame.K_r: r,
    pygame.K_t: t,
}
```

Then you can do:

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
for key, toProc in keyMap.items():
    if pressed[key]:
        toProc.PerformNote()
```

Comment: I appreciate the example, I thought the whole thing looked funny but I couldn't figure out why. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrieve a class member from a string with its name then try:

```
keyList = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't']
for currentKey in keyList:
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[getattr(pygame, 'K_' + currentKey)]:
        currentKey.PerformNote()
```

Comment: I appreciate answering my question while still using my somewhat broken design.